# Replace value with group means if N=1

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, statistics

I am trying to take grouped means for a dataset that has a lot of missing data, and for which SOME groups have 1 or 0 samples from which to derive means. I am trying to take a mean for each species within each ocean. However for species with only one value (or none) per ocean, I would like to use a "global" mean -- eg, a mean for that species across all oceans (rather than use only one value to take a "mean").

My data looks like this:

```
species<- c("turtle","turtle","turtle","turtle",
            "turtle","turtle","turtle","turtle",
            "shark",  "shark", "shark","shark",
            "shark",  "shark", "shark","shark",
             "bird")
gear<- c("t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t"  ) 
ocean<- c("north", "south", "east", "west", 
           "north", "south", "east", "west",
           "north", "south", "east", "west", 
           "north", "south", "east", "west",
           "north")
rate<-c( 0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.2 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.2 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.1 )

df<- as.data.frame(cbind(species, gear, region, rate))
df$rate<-as.numeric(df$rate)

db <- df %>%   
  group_by(species, gear, region) %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(rate),
            sd=sd(rate),
            n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(se = sd/sqrt(n), 
         upper_rate = mean + 1.96*se, 
         lower_rate = mean - 1.96*se)
```

What I would like to do is populate a dataframe with grouped means for EACH species AND ocean and gear, but for those with only one rate (eg birds), I want it to assign a "global" mean to all oceans. (Eg the bird mean in the south, east, and west oceans would be 0.10.

I am looking for the output to look like this:
[image]

I am trying to do this in a clean and reproducible way. I think it's really simple but can't seem to figure it out! Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are u looking to produce all possible combination with columns `species`, `gear` and `region`?
If so, shouldn't we have 24 rows in the final output? (since we have `c(2,3,4)` distinct values in the aforementioned columns respectively

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Clearly I can't even make the fake output! I will try to fix that. But yes I would like the dataframe to be populated for all combination of species, gear and region. But to assign "global" means for those species without enough data to produce a mean. if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

# dummy data
species <- c("turtle","turtle","turtle","turtle",
            "turtle","turtle","turtle","turtle",
            "shark",  "shark", "shark","shark",
            "shark",  "shark", "shark","shark",
            "bird")
gear <- c("t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t", "p", "t", "p",
         "t"  ) 
region <- c("north", "south", "east", "west", 
          "north", "south", "east", "west",
          "north", "south", "east", "west", 
          "north", "south", "east", "west",
          "north")
rate <-c( 0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.2 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.1 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.2 , 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
         0.1 )
df <- data.table(species, gear, region, rate)
# use setDT(df) if your dataframe isn't a data table already. Use class(df) to check

# group by level
x <- c('species', 'gear' ,'region')

# create all combinations
y <- CJ(df$species, df$gear, df$region, unique=T)
setnames(y, names(y), x)

# calculate mean, sd
z <- df[, .(mean = mean(rate)
             , sd = sd(rate)
             )
         , x
         ]

# join back to all combinations
a <- z[y, on=.(species, region ,gear)]

# calculate mean, sd at species level
b <- df[, .(mean_species_region = mean(rate)
             , sd_species_region = sd(rate)
             )
         , .(species)
         ]

# join back to all combinations
c <- b[a, on=.(species)]

# coalesce
c[, `:=` (mean = fcoalesce(mean, mean_species_region)
          , sd = fcoalesce(sd, sd_species_region)
          )
  ][, c('mean_species_region', 'sd_species_region') := NULL]

# clean environment
rm(list=letters[1:26])
```

Output:

```
    species gear region   mean         sd
 1:    bird    p   east 0.1000         NA
 2:    bird    p  north 0.1000         NA
 3:    bird    p  south 0.1000         NA
 4:    bird    p   west 0.1000         NA
 5:    bird    t   east 0.1000         NA
 6:    bird    t  north 0.1000         NA
 7:    bird    t  south 0.1000         NA
 8:    bird    t   west 0.1000         NA
 9:   shark    p   east 0.2625 0.10606602
10:   shark    p  north 0.2625 0.10606602
11:   shark    p  south 0.2000 0.00000000
12:   shark    p   west 0.4000 0.00000000
13:   shark    t   east 0.3000 0.00000000
14:   shark    t  north 0.1500 0.07071068
15:   shark    t  south 0.2625 0.10606602
16:   shark    t   west 0.2625 0.10606602
17:  turtle    p   east 0.2625 0.10606602
18:  turtle    p  north 0.2625 0.10606602
19:  turtle    p  south 0.2000 0.00000000
20:  turtle    p   west 0.4000 0.00000000
21:  turtle    t   east 0.3000 0.00000000
22:  turtle    t  north 0.1500 0.07071068
23:  turtle    t  south 0.2625 0.10606602
24:  turtle    t   west 0.2625 0.10606602
```

This is based on my understanding that you would like to end up with a table with ALL combinations using columns `species`, `gear` and `region`.
For those combination(s) which did not exist in original set or where combination only had one row in original data set, we will assign `mean` and `sd` grouped by `species`.

As you can see in output above we still have `NA` for `bird`'s `sd`. This is because we need at least 2 data points to calculate `sd`. But `bird` only had one row (data point) in original data.

For future examples it maybe better to use a more simplified data set. Anywho, hope this helps.